# SSIS Output to Flat File as 0.00

Tags: ssis

In SSIS I have a MONEY column in my OLE DB source that is formatted as 0.00.  I want to output this value to a flat file in exactly the same format.  So far, I've found two solutions:

1. Convert this to a string in my source and output a string to the file.  Since this is a flat file, it doesn't care HOW I got to 0.00.  It just uses this as the value.
2. Use a derived column in the data flow to generate a string with 0.00.  This is just a harder way to achieve the first solution, but it can work in situations where I can't control the format of the source data.

I don't really like either of these solutions since it requires some extra work to force the format to a string properly.  I can get the data to output to .00 if I change the data flow source output column to Numeric(18,2), but that doesn't completely solve the problem.  **Is there a way to output 0.00 without converting the data into a string?**

Comment: I'm still trying to determine why SSIS output ".00" and not "0.00". Be great to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ABS() regular expression. It remains numeric and produces the "0.00" you want.

```
ABS(numeric_expression)
```

** look at the mathematical regular expressions. ABS may not be what you want, if you have negative values in your source data.

Comment: This didn't precisely meet my needs since I need the negative values.  Ideally, I would prefer a solution that doesn't require transformations or script tasks, but I'll do it if there are no other options.

Comment: Marked as accepted since this is basically a dead question and your answer helped partially.